# how to increase brightness of a piece of a rgb image without overfolow?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, rgb, hsv

I have an image as shown below and I want to increase the brightness of the lightning section.

my input image:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
    import cv2 as cv
    import numpy as np

    src = cv.imread('./img.jpg')
    hsv_src = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    v = hsv_src[:,:,2]
    value = 50
    hsv_src[:,:,2]=np.where((255-v)<value,255,v+value) # v+value> 255 
    out = cv.cvtColor(hsv_src,cv.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

    cv.imshow('output',out)
    cv.waitKey(0)
```

but I eventually got this:
[image: result]

I just want to increase the brightness of lightning but what I'm watching now is increasing the brightness of the entire image. I'm honestly confused and don't know what to do.

Comment: Create a mask that is white for the lightning and black elsewhere. Process the whole image to increase the brightness of the lightning as desired. Then use the mask to composite the two images such that the brightened image is selected where the mask is white and the original image is selected where the mask in black ( or the inverted mask is white). There are lots of examples of blending two images with a mask if you search Google. See for example, https://www.learnopencv.com/alpha-blending-using-opencv-cpp-python/

Comment: What is "overfolow"? I think you mean "saturation"?

Comment: You can use this hsv_src[:,:,2]=np.clip(np.uint16(hsv_src[:,:,2])*1.2, 0, 255)

Comment: @AlexAlex Please convert your comment into an answer, and explain the operations being  used.

Comment: Your line containing `np.where()` increases the brightness **everywhere** in the image... not just the lightning. You need to make a mask that selects only the lightning and only apply your brightness increase in those places.

Answer (score 1):

You can not add, but multiply by a number. See example:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

src = cv.imread('zHSbF.jpg')
hsv_src = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
v = hsv_src[:,:,2]
k = 1.5
hsv_src[:,:,2]=np.clip(np.uint16(hsv_src[:,:,2])*k, 0, 255)
out = cv.cvtColor(hsv_src,cv.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cv.imwrite('out8.png', out)
cv.imshow('output',out)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

[image]